# how to make payments using firstdata - React & node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firstdata

I want to integrate the first data API to my website for card transactions, but I am not able to find the proper documentation to integrate with react and node js.

I have found an npm module, but it seems very old.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firstdata

Their official page also doesn't seem to work out https://developer.firstdata.com/marketplace/api/index.html#authentication

So please guide me to find a proper way to do it.

Note: I am from India

Comment: Hi Rittesh, Were you able to find any solution for same? I also wanted to do same using js.